# Longitudinal consistency of StrengthsFinder

Tags: personality, io-psychology

The [StrengthsFinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrengthsFinder) survey is a personality assessment which finds strengths which an individual can contribute to an organization. What is the consistency of this assessment:

1. When a person takes the assessment multiple times in short time
2. When a person retakes the assessment several months later

If there is variance, what is it most likely to be attributed to?

[The Gallup website](https://www.gallup.com/cliftonstrengths/en/249935/strengths-change-answering-big-question.aspx), claims:

> Gallup's test-retest statistical correlation studies of
>   CliftonStrengths assessments yield a correlation hovering around 0.7.

However, it does not cite any source.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like StrengthFinder and CliftonStrengths are owned by Gallup organisation and there is commercial registration of the tests? The same way as psychometric testing can be commercialised and protected by intellectual property law, it seems that Gallup has done the same with those tests.

As the result, research and testing into those instruments are very limited and stifled by the risk of litigation by the Gallup organisation. Makes it hard to independently verify and test the assumptions and studies done by Gallup unfortunately.